# Project two graphs

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have created two graphs from two different csv files which I would like to analyse as a multiplex network.

But before I start the analysis, I need to connect them or project one onto the other. I have read that I need to use the projected_graph function, which does not work with my graphs.

Here is my code. Is there any other way to do it or what am I missing here. Thanks for the help.

```
G=nx.Graph()

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(data_fenotype, source='Disorder', target='Disorder_category',edge_attr=['Symptom'],create_using=nx.Graph())

#print(G.number_of_edges())
#print(G.number_of_nodes())

B=nx.Graph()
B = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(data_genom, source='Disorder', target='Disorder_category',edge_attr=['Symptom'],create_using=nx.Graph())

#print(B.number_of_edges())
#print(B.number_of_nodes())

#B = bipartite.projected_graph(B, G.nodes())

#print(B.nodes())
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'connecting'? Connect namesake nodes with edges?

Comment: I want to project the networks.

Comment: Are you looking for the union or composition of the two graphs? Maybe you want to take a look at https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/operators.html. A projection of a bipartite graph is described here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_network_projection and is probably not the thing you are looking for.